# How to restore model(Graph and weights) and fine tune some variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to **pre-train** a model on dataset_A with tensorflow, save the model with tf.train.Saver into checkpoint files. And then restore the model next time and **fine tune some variables** in the graph(i.e. not all the trainable_variables) with dataset_B.

In the pre-training phase(pretrain.py), the variable is defined as follow:

```
with tf.variable_scope("finetune"):
    full_connect_W = tf.get_variable(name="full_connect_W", shape=[n_hidden, num_class], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
```

In the fine-tuning phase(finetune.py), I have to get the variable for the [optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer)'s **var_list**. The codes bellow raise ValueError:

```
with tf.variable_scope("finetune") as scope:
    scope.reuse_variables()
    full_connect_w = tf.get_variable("full_connect_W:0")
```

> ValueError: Variable finetune/full_connect_W:0 does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
>   enter code here

Even if I remove the suffix ":0" in the variable name, same error raised again.

> ValueError: Variable finetune/full_connect_W does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?

I managed to solve this problem in an ugly way. I restore the checkpoint file and find that **finetune/full_connect_W:0** is the first item in [tf.trainable_variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables). So I get the variable like this:

```
full_connect_W = tf.trainable_variables()[0]
```

- So the first question is: Is there any methods like **get_variable** or **get_tensor_by_xxx** to get the variable I want to fine tune?

---

Another problem is, when I try to train the model with a new optimizer defined in the finetune phase (finetune.py), some error occurs. It seems the optimizer needs to be initialized.

```
full_connect_W = tf.trainable_variables()[0]
full_connect_b = tf.trainable_variables()[1]
finetune_varlist = [full_connect_W, full_connect_b]
cost = g.get_tensor_by_name("cost:0")
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost, var_list=finetune_varlist)
```

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value beta1_power_2
>
> [[Node: beta1_power_2/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@finetune/full_connect_W"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]
>   Caused by op u'beta1_power_2/read', defined at:
>
> File "finetune_lstm_videotitle_test.py", line 72, in 
>       optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost, var_list=finetune_varlist)

But if I initialize with tf.initialize_all_variables(), all the weights(variables) trained in the pre-trainning phrase with be reset.

- So the second question is: How can I fine tune specific variables and fixed other variables?